# bitbucket отменить изменения файла

Tags: git

Случайно включил в коммит файл, и запушил на удаленный сервер.

Как мне отменить изменения именно этого файла на удаленном сервере?

Answer (score 3):

Необходимо вернуться на коммит без отмены изменений:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

Потом убираем ненужный файл из коммита:

```
git reset HEAD путь/к/файлу
```

Снова коммитим

```
git commit -c ORIG_HEAD
```

И подменяем изменения на сервере

```
git push origin <название вашей ветки> --force
```

Comment: Спасаибо. Очень полезный надор команд

Comment: Полезный, но только очень вредный. Форсированный пуш... да...

Comment: Если вы уже залили что-то на удалённый сервер, к которому у вас доступ только через Git, не то чтобы у вас были какие-то другие варианты кроме `push --force`

Comment: revert или просто исправляющий коммит.